# How to ask what tree the leaf on Canada's flag belongs to using "of" instead of "belong"?

Tags: questions, possessives

Canada's flag contains a leaf. I want to ask what tree that leaf belongs to using preposition "of" instead of the verb "belong". Can I ask like this:

1. What tree does Canada's flag contain a leaf of?
2. What tree is it a leaf of on Canada's flag?

Comment: "The leaf of which tree is shown on the flag of Canada?"

Comment: @KateBunting Please refrain from answering in the comments. It subverts the quality control mechanisms of the site, and the comments can be deleted without warning

Comment: @nick012000 - It wasn't necessarily intended as an answer, just a suggestion. ,

Answer (score 3):

The people who have answered using phrases like *a leaf from which tree* are giving you English. But as far as I'm concerned none of them is everyday English.

I would say, almost like your question

> Which tree does the Canadian flag show a leaf from?

(Your "what" and "of" are both possible, but this is a more natural form, to my ear).

Your second sentence is grammatical, but confusing to read.

Comment: How about "What tree is the leaf on Canada's flag a leaf of?"? Is it grammatical?

Comment: @Vova: It's grammatical, but awkward and wordy, so I don't think many people would say it.

Answer (score 3):

A more natural way to ask this: "What kind of leaf is on Canada's flag?" Or even: "What leaf is on Canada's flag?" People should understand this given that different kinds of leaves come from different kinds of trees.

Answer (score 2):

> Canada's flag contains a leaf of which tree?

However, I would probably say,

> Canada's flag contains a leaf from which tree?