# Is "which tree is it that the Canada's flag shows a leaf of?" grammatical?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I know that "what is it that you want?" is grammatical. I made up the question "which tree is it that the Canadian flag shows a leaf of?" using my knowledge of English. I really need to know if it's correct, as it helps me to figure out how English works. Is it correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ask what tree the leaf on Canada's flag belongs to using "of" instead of "belong"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/300184/how-to-ask-what-tree-the-leaf-on-canadas-flag-belongs-to-using-of-instead-of)

Answer (score 3):

The form in your question is grammatical.
(The form in the thread title isn't. It should not have the word *the*).

It's also a bit awkward. To ask for the same information, you could ask

> What tree's leaf is on the Canadian flag?

or just

> What kind of leaf is shown on the flag of Canada?